# Disable linked personal accounts for MVC active directory sign in

Tags: c#, .net, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I have followed the instructions [here](https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) to create an MVC application with the default configuration to authenticate with Azure active directory.

The Microsoft sign in page presents an option to choose whether I sign in with a 'work / school' account or 'personal' account. This is because i have a personal account set up with the same email as my organisational one.

I would like to prevent personal account sign in.

I know that appending the query string (msafed=0) to the login URL does exactly this, however I don't have a clue where to implement this in the default authentication code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, `msafed=0` is the way to go. If you're using OWIN, try hooking the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` notification in the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`. There you can append extra query parameters in the outgoing request.